# How to add or apply a CSS class to an entire HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I usually add a class to the body of an HTML document like this:

```
document.body.classList.toggle('darkClass', this.props.isDark)
```

But I am not sure how to get the entire `html` element.
How can I reference it in Javascript?

```
var html = ?
html.classList.toggle(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**document.documentElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) to get the entire `html` element. And also see it's `innerHTML` property.

```js
console.log(document.documentElement);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>TEST</div>
  </body>
</html>
```